# Blackberry Package Project for Multiple OS Targets/Versions

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I'm using the Eclipse plug-in and my app runs on the following simulators: 9800, 9700, 8900 ,i.e, it is compatible with OS versions 5 and 6. However , when I package the application to run it on a device, the **.alx file is generated correctly but there is also a folder called '6.0.0' with all the other files like .cod, .jar, etc. My question is, shouldn't there be a similar folder '5.0.0' with files for OS version 5**? And if yes, then how do I go about generating it?Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just incase someone else is as frustrated by this as I was here's the solution:
[Changing BlackBerry JRE to an Older Version (Eclipse Plug-in)](http://codejunkster.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/changing-blackberry-jre-to-an-older-version-eclipse-plug-in/)

Answer (score 1):

Just Check the project properties, it will be 6.0 JRE.

To be clear, you need to install the 5.0 in Eclipse by going through Help menu-Install Software, and add the Blackberry update site: `http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java`.  Download the required OS from there.

Then, right click in the project, go to properties of the project and in it go Java Build Path, and under it, go to Libraries tab, you will find JRE to be 6.0, you need to change it to 5.0.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your reply. I had installed JDE component 5.0.0    but when I changed the library to this component and then ran the project, it runs fine on simulator but shows Packaging Error- "An internal error has occurred- java.lang.NullPointerException". So I just made the code compatible with 5 but changed the JRE back to 6.0.0...now it runs on simulator but still won't package for 5...sorry if I'm missing out some stupid small thing here but I'm a newbie :(

Comment: And when you say 5.0 does it mean JDE component package 5.0 will do or do I have to get something else?